# Can I change the order of two terms when factoring: $x^2(x^2-4-3x)$ to $x^2(x^2-3x-4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm doing homework and I'm stuck on this assignment:
$$x^4 - 4x^2 - 3x^3$$

I figured this would equal
$$x^2(x^2-4-3x)$$

Now I know if I would change the order to
$$x^2(x^2-3x-4)$$

I can factorise it again, but my question is if it's allowed changing the order like that in algebra.

Comment: Yes. It works in the same way that $-5 + 6 = +6 - 5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the law of commutativity (together with the law of associativity) allows you to rearrange summands (or factors) in arbitrary order. (However, because these laws hold for *addition*, not for *subtraction*, You better view the minus sign as part of the coefficient for this, i.e. $x^2-4-3x=x^2+(-4)+(-3x) = x^2+(-3x)+(-4) = x^2-3x-4$, just to prevent you from falling for $x-5=5-x$ or the like)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do so as addition of real numbers is commutative.(Considering $x\in R$)

Addition is commutative means  $\forall x,y\in R$ , $(x+y)=(y+x)$

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, but thanks mate, a yes or no answer is all I needed.

Comment: Now do you get it??? @user1534664

Comment: I've been programming for about 3 years and I've been adviced to improve my math, so I've asked my teacher for some assignments. I'm only on page 9, so I dont know what all the symbols mean yet, do you think its wise to learn the symbols with so little experience?

Comment: (x+y)=(y+x) seems logical to me, though :)

Comment: Learning something new is always advisable .But I dont think to learn basic mathematics you need to learn these symbols that well.